# What is the English name of the “Hohe Wächter” faction in Taldor?

Tags: golarion, adventure-path, translations, german

We are going to start the *Reign of Winter* Adventure Path next week and our GM said we are part of a faction (or guild?). Since we are playing in German he told us the faction is “*Hohe Wächter*”, which is translated literally as “high guards”. I guess the translation must be different since I cannot find anything on the internet about it. I checked the Faction Guide already and could not find anything there either. Apparently one of the faction's orders is to secured the borders of Taldor.

What is the right name of this faction in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English translation is probably the **High Sentinels**:

> For many years, an organization of Taldan rangers called the High Sentinels [have been] charged with guarding the forest against Qadiran aggression,
>   lest Taldor's ancient enemy use the wood to hide another invasion force. ([*Snows of Summer*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ubg?Pathfinder-Adventure-Path-67-The-Snows-of-Summer) 16)

Little additional information outside the adventure path is available for the organization; there's no High Sentinels page on the [*Pathfinder* wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=high%20sentinels&go=Go), for example. (There is a [Taldor](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Taldor) page, but [*Pathfinder Chronicles: Taldor, Echoes of Glory*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8853?Pathfinder-Companion-Taldor-Echoes-of-Glory) is for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* (hence its OGL designation) despite the presence of artifacts from it on the *d20PFSRD* like the prestige class [lion's blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/i-m/lion-blade).).

However, by having the PCs start as part of this organization, the GM has chosen an interesting way to begin the campaign, and were I you I wouldn't look too deeply for more information lest some minor plot points be spoiled.